# Flat array to tree

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
0 => [
  'pid' => 'all'
  'id' => 0
]
1 => [
  'pid' => 0
  'id' => 1
]
2 => [
  'pid' => 1
  'id' => 2
]
3 => [
  'pid' => 1
  'id' => 3
]
4 => [
  'pid' => 0
  'id' => 5
]
5 => [
  'pid' => 5
  'id' => 7
]
```

And now I want to create a recursive tree out of this, so that I can generate a HTML structure. The array then should look like this:

```
0 => [
  'id' => 0,
  'children' => [
    0 => [
      'id' => 1
      'children' => [
        0 => [
          'id' => 2
        ]
        1 => [
          'id' => 3
        ]
      ]
    ]
    1 => [
      'id' => 5
      'children' => [
        0 => [
          'id' => 7
        ]
      ]
    ]
]
```

How can I do that? I couldn't find any solutions that could be helpful here.

Comment: When is something a "child"?  Maybe you could code something and we could help you fixing any issues you had with that.

Comment: Bah - closed. :( See here for the solution **http://ideone.com/kUH7yN**